# how to apply roles in middleware routes

Tags: rest, go, authorization, middleware, roles

i want to set middleware authorization with roles in golang, to restrict some API to roles, e.g. for admin access all API, for workers1 some of API

I've done authorization with jwt and middleware, now im trying to inject roles to exising code

Authorization package

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := &models.User{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(user)
    if err != nil {
        var resp = map[string]interface{}{"status": false, "message": "Ivalid request"}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
        return
    }
    resp := FindOne(user.Email, user.Password)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
}
func FindOne(email, password string) map[string]interface{} {
    user := &models.User{}

    if err := database.DBGORM.Where("Email = ?", email).First(user).Error; err != nil {
        var resp = map[string]interface{}{"status": false, "message": "Email address not found"}
        return resp
    }
    expiresAt := time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 5).Unix()

    errf := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(password))
    if errf != nil && errf == bcrypt.ErrMismatchedHashAndPassword { //Password does not match!
        var resp = map[string]interface{}{"status": false, "message": "Invalid login credentials. Please try again"}
        return resp
    }

    tk  := &models.Token{
        UserID: user.ID,
        Name:   user.Name,
        Email:  user.Email,
        Role: user.Role,
        StandardClaims: &jwt.StandardClaims{
            ExpiresAt: expiresAt,
        },
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod("HS256"), tk)

    tokenString, error := token.SignedString([]byte("secret"))
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

    var resp = map[string]interface{}{"status": false, "message": "logged in"}
    resp["token"] = tokenString //Store the token in the response
    return resp
}
```

JWT Verification function

```
func JwtVerify(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        var header = r.Header.Get("x-access-token") //Grab the token from the header

        header = strings.TrimSpace(header)

        if header == "" {
            //Token is missing, returns with error code 403 Unauthorized
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Exception{Message: "Missing auth token"})
            return
        }
        tk := &models.Token{}

        _, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(header, tk, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte("secret"), nil
        })

        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Exception{Message: err.Error()})
            return
        }
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "user", tk)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx)) 
    })
}
```

this is routes

```
func Handlers()  *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.Use(CommonMiddleWare)

    router.HandleFunc("/api/login", controller.Login)
    router.HandleFunc("/api/register", controller.CreateUser)
    router.HandleFunc("/api/getclientbylogin/login={login}", controller.GetNowClientHardwareByLogin).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/getclientbyname/fullname={lname}&{fname}&{sname}", controller.GetProfilesByFullNames).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/getaddress/{type}={value}", controller.GetLocation).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/getfullnames/{type}", controller.GetNames).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/operstatus={login}", controller.CheckEquipment).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/api/cablediagnostic={login}", controller.CheckInventory).Methods("GET")

    s := router.PathPrefix("/auth").Subrouter()
    s.Use(utils.JwtVerify)
    s.HandleFunc("/api/getname/{type}={value}", controller.GetName).Methods("GET")


    return router
}
func CommonMiddleWare(next http.Handler) http.Handler  {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        res.Header().Add("Content-type", "application/json")
        res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Connection, Host, Origin, User-Agent, Referer, Cache-Control, X-header")
        next.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
}
```

How can i realize roles to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `mux` is `gorilla/mux`. This is something close to what I am doing in my project:

First register routes with a name:

```
router.HandleFunc("/api/register", controller.CreateUser).Name("createUser")
```

Then use that name from a middleware to do a role/method lookup:

```
currentRoute:=mux.CurrentRoute(request)
if currentRoute!=nil {
   if !checkRole(ctx,currentRoute.GetName()) {
       // return 403
   }
}
```

Where `checkRole` is a function that gets user roles from ctx, and using a lookup table, determines whether the user's role includes the route name.